# Как Увеличить каждый элемент каждого из массивов, вложенных в массив JS?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста увеличить все элементы в два раза:

```
let myArray = [
     [-22, 93, 15, -110],
     [99, 1011, 68, 235],
     [11, 86, -12],
     [11, 24, 56, 112, -12]
 ];
```

На ум ничего не приходит кроме как:

```
let numsArr2 = numsArr.map(num => num * 2);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
let numsArr10 = numsArr.map(ar => ar.map(num => (num + 10)));
```

Comment: большое спасибо! все работает!

Comment: @Glenn Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.